# Bridging the geometry of two parts of an object that were created separately

Tags: modeling

I am creating a chair and I created the backrest and the seat portion separately. I joined them and I want to model the transition between them but I don't know how to go about it
[image: Screenshot of chair]
Here's the chair I'm referencing:

[image: Porada Ester Chair]
<sub>(source: [chaplins.co.uk](https://chaplins.co.uk/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/p/o/porada-ester-carver-dining-chair-01_1.jpg))</sub>

Link to my blender file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtZBZThYAyjaHVjUEk2TFAxcFk

Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible to connect this meshes in actual state. Consider modeling beckrest also low poly and ten use Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth things out. Have in mind quad based topology and proper Edge Flow for easier use of Proximity Loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LukeD is right.
You could in edit mode use *select edge loop* and *Dissolve Edges* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) to decrease the number of edges of the armchair. Subdivide the lower edged parts to get more edges to work on. Try to conect these vertices now.